Preventing Programmatic Downloads of Audio Content
I host podcasts on Amazon CloudFront with pre-signed URLs and use basic JavaScript in my Audio Web Player to deter downloads. Despite these measures, I'm concerned about the potential for tech-savvy users or scripts to systematically download all episodes.
I'm seeking advice on strategies to enhance content security against such algorithmic downloads, without overly complicating user access. Possible approaches I've considered include improved authentication, rate limiting, or more advanced JavaScript. However, I'm open to any effective methods that balance content protection with user experience.
Would appreciate insights or recommendations on preventing programmatic access to my podcasts. Thanks!

You didn't tell us the URL of "my podcasts", so it's hard to dig into the details. Assume a Loyal Fan catches up each weekend to the backlog of your daily podcasts. What would distinguish such a Fan from a Bot that does downloads each weekend? For bots with unlimited calendar time available to them, is this even a solvable problem?
